# How to get confusion matrix from the below model?

Tags: python, confusion-matrix, conv-neural-network

The X represents features and Y represents labels for image classification. I am using CNN for binary image classification purpose  like that of cats and dogs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


X = np.array(pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb")))
Y = np.array(pickle.load(open("Y.pickle","rb")))

x_test = np.array(pickle.load(open("x_test.pickle","rb")))
y_test = np.array(pickle.load(open("y_test.pickle","rb")))


# X = np.array(pickle.load(open("x_train.pickle","rb")))
# Y = np.array(pickle.load(open("y_train.pickle","rb")))

#scaling our image data
X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()
#model.add(Conv2D(64 ,(3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(64 ,(3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(2048))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

np.argmax(model.add(Dense(2)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
             optimizer = "adam",
             metrics = ['accuracy'])

predicted = model.predict(x_test)
print(predicted.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predicted))
```

The output of predicted and y_test shapes are (90, 2) and
(90,) and when I used confusion matrix it flushes:-
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous-multioutput targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

predicted = model.predict(x_test)
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predicted.round()))
```

Here's scikit learn documentation for confusion matrix:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

**Edit:**

**Advice:**

- Prefer using Softmax activation on output layer and whether it is binary or multi label classification. Use softmax with number of nodes in output layer = no of classes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I had used what you said but still its showing error! Am I doing anything wrong. I have save edits in my code.

Comment: Your predicted and test shapes are different. Because you are loading y_test from x_test pickle. Line : y_test = np.array(pickle.load(open("x_test.pickle","rb"))).
I guess the pickle file should be "y_test.pickle". you've written it wrong. Please check

Comment: I have changed according to what you said but still I am getting the same error with x_shape and y_shape be (90, 1)
(90,).

Comment: Okay I've got it, why you are getting this error. It's because you've applied sigmoid function on output layer and not softmax layer. So, the values in predicted values are in decimals, where as values in y_test are either 1 or 0.  So, you can round up the predicted values using round() function. Check my answer , I've edited my answer.

Comment: okay! means I need to use softmax as an activation function at the dense layer with 2 as number of units?

Comment: Thanks for your kind help and time! I have used and corrected my code according to what you said. It's working fine but the confusion matrix which I am getting is [[ 0 50]
 [ 0 40]]  which says that my data is not equally distributed. So do I need to shuffle the x_train?

Comment: you have used. Dense(1), it should be Dense(2). So, as output you'll get 2 values, then you have to take index with max value as output. (you can use argmax() for this purpose).

Comment: I edited my code as per you said but still I am getting ValueError. Please check.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216187/confusion-matrix
Join this room, and post your latest code .

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example how we can get the confusion matrix using the PyCM library:
you need to install the pycm library in anaconda or by using pip3

```
conda install -c sepandhaghighi pycm

from pycm import *

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm, normalize=False, title='Confusion matrix', cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    """
    This function modified to plots the ConfusionMatrix object.
    Normalization can be applied by setting 'normalize=True'.
    Code Reference : 
    http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html
    """
    plt_cm = []
    for i in cm.classes :
        row=[]
        for j in cm.classes:
            row.append(cm.table[i][j])
        plt_cm.append(row)
    plt_cm = np.array(plt_cm)
    if normalize:
        plt_cm = plt_cm.astype('float') / plt_cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]     
    plt.imshow(plt_cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(cm.classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, cm.classes, rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, cm.classes)

    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = plt_cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(plt_cm.shape[0]), range(plt_cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, format(plt_cm[i, j], fmt),
                horizontalalignment="center",
                color="white" if plt_cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('Actual')
    plt.xlabel('Prediction')
```

.....

```
svm.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_predicted = svm.predict(x_test)

#Get the confusion Matrix:
cm = ConfusionMatrix(actual_vector=y_test, predict_vector=y_predicted)

#Print classes
print("[INFO] Clases")
print(cm.classes)
#Print the table of cmatrix
print(cm.table)
#indicators of the confusion matrix
print(cm)
```

greetings!